# how to hand then promise as sync

Tags: javascript, async.js

I came a across a async js function that i need to use.
My issue came across the need to "stop" the js until this function returns what is supposed to.

The function "svgAsPngUri" returns the promisse - as described in documentation https://github.com/exupero/saveSvgAsPng

```
   async function GetBase64FromSVG(element) {
        let response = await svgAsPngUri(element, null).then(async uri => { return uri });
        return response;
    }
```

i did try the await and also using the async with no sucess.
any help?
or am i thinking this the wrong way?

Comment: Well, probably you should provide some context where you are invoking this function. As for now, you can simplify it:

async function GetBase64FromSVG(element) {
        return svgAsPngUri(element, null)
    }

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to "stop" the JavaScript code until the promise resolves. The whole purpose of the asynchronous code is to free the main thread for other code execution while `svgAsPngUri` operates (JavaScript's runtime is single threaded).

However, you can make your code look like it's synchronous with `async`/`await` like this:

```
function GetBase64FromSVG(element) {
    return svgAsPngUri(element, null);
}

async function foo() {
    // ...
    const result = await GetBase64FromSVG(element);
    // ...
}
```